# Adding space between clickable images without making the margin space clickable

Tags: html, css, button, icons, margin

https://jsfiddle.net/ets9rmw9/1/

In reference to the icons in the upper right hand corner of the website, I am trying to put some space between them, however if I use margins to space them out, the margin space becomes clickable as well, this is not exactly what I'd like. I can't seem to find out how to get the space between them without making it clickable, padding and margins don't work.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="logo" src="Logo.png" />
<nav>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="navlist"><a href="#">Properties</a></li>
  <li class="navlist"><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
  <li class="navlist"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="imgs">
<a href="#" title="Twitter" alt=" Icon"><img src="twitter.png" /></a>
<a href="#" title="Facebook" alt=" Icon"><img src="facebook.png" /></a>
<a href="#" title="Instagram" alt=" Icon"><img src="instagram.png" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
<p class="buttons">Real estate</p>
</footer>


body {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin: 0;
display: table;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(nice.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
height: auto;
background-color: whitesmoke;
}

footer {
background-color: #cbb492;
display: table-row;
height: 2px;
text-align: center;
}

li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-variant: small-caps;
color: black;
}

li:hover {
background-color: #cbb492;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid gray;
}

nav {
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-top: 2px;
background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.logo {
height: 28px;
width: 90px;
z-index: -10;
}

p {
color: white;
font-size: 6px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 20px;
} 

.navlist {
display: inline;
padding-left: 30px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 5.3px;
padding-bottom: 6.2px;
}

.nav {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
margin: 1px;
top: 0px;
margin-top: 3px;
}

.imgs {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
float: right;
width: 60px;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 5.5px;
padding-bottom: 5.5px;
}

.imgs img {
width: 20%;
height: 20%;
opacity: 0.7;
margin-right: 5px;
} 

.imgs img:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: The small space to the right of each image is clickable, due to the margins I had added

Answer (score 0):

Please add this css:

```
.imgs img {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `display:inline-block` in `img` tag and add margin in `a` tag. Like this:

```
.imgs img {  
   display:inline-block;
}
.imgs a{
  margin-right:5px;     
}
```

Here is your update fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/ets9rmw9/3/

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why making the margin for .imgs img was clickable, but it's not for .imgs a

Comment: Because if u add margin in img and img is inside in a tag.. to space was come in a tag ... so it will clickable ... so avoid to add margin in img tag..